# Why are my POST actions not found in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This is my DefaultApi configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
   defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)

[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyClass obj)
```

How come `GET` works but using `POST` I get a `404 Not Found` error?

Any ideas or suggestions?

**Edit:**

Client JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Content("~/api/controllername")",
    data: args,
    200: function (data) {
          ......
        }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you add the `{action}` to your route, the 'magical' code that uses the prefix of the method name to determine get/post functionality doesn't work.

You need to add `[HttpPost]` attribute to your `Post(MyClass obj)` method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyClass obj)
{
    // ...
}

// equivalent to:
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DefaultAction(MyClass obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note in the above, your method name can be used to define the action name, so you could just rename your methods given the route you are using instead of using the `ActionName` attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `{controller}/{id}/{action}`, especially with id being optional, I'm not sure if that is related to your issues. I usually use `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. I would also try adding `[HttpGet]` to your get method as I've had to do that on another project.

Comment: Didn't work too... basically i use controller/id/action because i use get api/controller  it's weird i have a different api controller thats pretty much the same and everything is working fine... It has to be something stupid...

Comment: Didn't work too... basically i use controller/id/action because i use get api/controller to getall, get api/controller/id to get single object post api/controller to create new  and get api/controller/id/action to get a nested object from a single request. for example api/request/23/getstudents or single student api/request/23/getstudent/3.  it's weird i have a different api controller that is pretty much the same and everything is working fine... It has to be something stupid...

Comment: I figure out the issue... I had a different Map Route that it was messing up things.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem and the solution was to add `[FromBody]` to the method's paramter like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostIncreaseViewCounter([FromBody]int id)
{
}
```